# AngularJS/jQuery: changing text in span doesn't fire resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble getting jQuery's `resize` event to fire on a `span`, after I've changed the text inside the span.

I'm applying the event handlers to the `span` element using an AngularJS directive:

```
angular.module("test.directives", [])
    .directive("trackSize", ["$parse", function($parse) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            function callback() {
                var size = { w: element.width(), h: element.height() };
                scope[attrs.trackSize].call(scope, size);
            }
            element.on("resize", function() {
                console.log("resize");
                scope.$apply(callback);
            });
            callback();
        };
    }]);
```

but I'm not seeing the callback fire when the text inside the `span` changes.  If it's relevant: the text is being changed using an embedded AngularJS expression.

My actual (full) code snippet can be seen on the jsFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/KkctU/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resize event isn't meant for elements inside the document like a span. It's made for use on the window only.

[Here is a plugin that might help you](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/). I've not used it, but it seems like it's along the right track for you.

In the end, though, it might be better/easier to just set up a watch in your directive on whatever is bound to it, then check to see if the height and width have changed when the text changes. Just as an idea:

```
app.directive('trackSize', function () {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       var w = element.width(),
           h = element.height();
       scope.$watch(attrs.trackSize, function(v) {
           element.text(v);
           var w2 = element.width(),
               h2 = element.height();
           if(w != w2 || h != h2) {
              //TODO: do something here, the size has changed.
           }           
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: The `onresize` event seems to be supported on pretty much every element type: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp.  Does this not correlate with the jQuery `resize` handler?

Comment: W3SCHOOLS IS BAD... there I said it.  Always skip their links. ALWAYS.  [Here is Mozilla's page on the matter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize) ... only the window will raise the event.

Comment: [Friends don't let friends use w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). Check out the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-resize

Comment: @BrandonTilley Alright, alright; w3schools is bad.  I'm just a po' ole' systems software guy trying out the Web side of the pond.  Glad I got the intervention early :-)

Comment: @blesh: looks like I'll be accepting this one, but your example answer isn't entirely what I was looking for -- in this case, we're `$watch`-ing the attribute bound to the DOM element, not the actual size of the DOM element.  Is there any solution for the latter?

Comment: Isn't changing the size of the text the thing that is the trigger for the size of the element to change? Go to the source.

Comment: Otherwise you're going to have to do something like set up some sort of interval that checks the size of the element and triggers if it changes. That gets a little complicated though, as you probably wouldn't want to spin up a new interval for every element you're checking.  You're way better off just monitoring the cause of the resize, whatever that may be. Less overhead and less work.